# NSUserDefaults gets reset

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have an ios app, and recently have been getting some reports from users about their settings getting reset.
The settings are saved using `NSUserDefaults`.

My question is, can the user defaults get corrupt/reset for some reason?

A few notes about how I use it:

- When I start my app, I store default values only if the keys doesn't exist using `registerDefaults` (this is done to take care of the "first install" scenario).
- Most of the aforementioned reports describe the app crashing, and then when it is reopened the settings are reset to default.
- My usage of `NSUserDefaults` is pretty straightforward - saving `numbers/strings`, reading them sometimes, etc. Nothing too fancy. I don't remove keys.

Some code examples:

For example, I'm saving the data in different places using:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:@"FirstLevel" forKey:@"Level"];
[defaults setInteger:100 forKey:@"Score"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I read using:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int intValue = [defaults integerForKey:@"Score"];
return intValue;
```

So, can something cause the user defaults to get reset/corrupt somehow?

More generally, can it be related to the app crashing that was reported, even if the crash is not directly as a result of writing/reading from user defaults?

Comment: Posting some code will be useful.

Comment: please add your code here then we can able to understand .what is exactly problem .

Comment: I will happily add some code, though it's more of a general question regarding known issues with NSUserDefaults getting reset on crashes. The code itself is as straightforward as it gets, but I'll post some anyway.

Comment: Are you calling `synchronise` after you are saving data to `NSUserDefaults`? If you don't it's possible that the data is not saved in the database because the `synchronise` method is never called  due  to the crash that is happening.

Comment: Yes, I call `synchronize` always after saving data.

Comment: Can you post how you are checking and setting the default values for NSUserDefaults? It seems odd to me that you are checking for existing keys before setting the defaults, because the usual way to do this is with the [registerDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDDCDB) method and there is no need to check if other values have been set.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, as I am indeed using `registerDefaults`. I just described basically what it does. Thanks, will edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: you don't need to call `-synchronize` *"always after saving data"*. maybe somewhere this `-synchronize` method call must be causing the issue (_actually, you need to replicate the crash scenario to figure out the issue_)

Comment: I agree that it would be best of course to reproduce it, however this is a very rare crash and I didn't encounter it myself. Can too many `synchronize` calls cause such an issue?

Comment: As an aside, and not related to your actual problem, `integerforKey:` returns an `NSInteger` not an `int`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I see the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here. Note that Apple's current docs for synchronize() say that this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it is only swiped out when app is deleted.  Since your NSUserDefaults' reset issue was preceding by the app crashed, I would start by figure out the crashing issue.